# Fluid Image Contained in Fluid Container

Tags: html, css

I have an image wrapper with a maximum height and width constraint (in this example 300x200), and I'm trying to place a fluid image inside the container that respects those constraints.

The width of the image scales as expected, however the image's height always overflows beyond the parent div. What's the proper way to get this image to scale appropriately with CSS alone?

```css
.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #eef;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.figure-image-wrapper {
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.figure-image {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.figure-caption {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <figure class="figure">
    <div class="figure-image-wrapper">
      <img src="//placehold.it/700x700" class="figure-image"/>
    </div>
    <figcaption class="figure-caption">This is my caption. It's expect to span beyond the width of the image. The image above should scale within a 300x200 .figure-image-wrapper</figcaption>
  </figure>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
.figure-image-wrapper {
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.figure-image {
    max-width: inherit;
    max-height: inherit;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/ngbrquen/)

Comment: Problem there is the image no longer has a fluid width. Scale the pane horizontally, and you'll notice the image maintains its width at 300px. Thanks for the attempt!

Answer (score 0):

Ahah! The trick is to have only the `max-height` of the image inherit from the parent wrapper:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #eef;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.figure-image-wrapper {
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center; /* Added: Center the image */
}

.figure-image {
  max-width: 100%;
  /* Removed: height: auto; */
  max-height: inherit; /* Added */
}

.figure-caption {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <figure class="figure">
    <div class="figure-image-wrapper">
      <img src="//placehold.it/700x700" class="figure-image"/>
    </div>
    <figcaption class="figure-caption">This is my caption. It's expect to span beyond the width of the image. The image above should scale within a 300x200 .figure-image-wrapper</figcaption>
  </figure>    
</div>
```